# how to change highlight color on editText field

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

Below is a screen shot of a custom edit text field i have in my android app.  While you are type a given word, the text for the word you are currently typing highlights in grey and shows the text as black, until you hit the space bar at which time the text turns white as expected.  Is there a way to change the color of the highlight and the text that is highlighted?

[image]

my edit text xml looks like this

```
 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/searchField"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="44dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHighlight ="#ff0000"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null" >
                </EditText>
```

**the whole layout**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!--
         As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
    -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff" >



        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.sapientnitro.inhouse.drop.components.DRPCustomMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />



        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_center_local"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_center_on_local_up" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="#ddffffff" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_menu"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_search"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_menu_up" />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_create"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_search"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_create_up" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_search"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_search_up" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#ddffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:background="#dd00cccb" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/searchBox"
                    android:layout_width="238dp"
                    android:layout_height="44dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/search_field" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/clear"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_clear_field" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/searchField"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="44dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHighlight ="@color/white"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null" >
                </EditText>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cancelBTN"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:text="@string/cancel" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/search_results_container"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/search_results_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/header_artists"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="#dd00cccb" />

                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/results_artists"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/header_followers"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="#dd00cccb" />

                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/results_followers"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/header_places"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="#dd00cccb" />

                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/results_places"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#dd00cccb"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_transparent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="#dd00cccb"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_transparent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: How did you style your header/edittext like that ?

Comment: like what?  just set the background to null and put an image below it

Answer (score 32):

I was able to change the highlight of my edit text by adding this line to my themes.xml file:

```
<item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/m_highlight_blue</item>
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the color of the selction-handlers that you can drag?

Comment: Do you how know how to set this programatically ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes, you can. The cursors take the color of the "colorAccent" in your theme file. Change the color of ColorAccent as per your requirement in your theme file.

Comment: @sharibahmed When an Android developer says "programmatically", he means "using a programming language (Java/Kotlin/...), during runtime". Not XML which is static. So what I meant is: How can I get the color by using Java/Kotlin?

Comment: @androiddeveloper bro, you did not mention the word "programmatically".
You cannot change theme programmatically as they are immutable during runtime but you can create another theme with your required color and add that theme to your VIEW.

Comment: @sharibahmed Sorry I was confused and thought someone else's comment is mine. Anyway, it's still weird though. The CTOR of the class takes from the theme too, and you can give a theme programmatically, but you can't set it up without XML ?

Answer (score 20):

**Simple, just use TextHightLight Property in XML Mode**

```
android:textColorHighlight="#ff0000"
```

or add this in your theme

```
<item name="android:textColorHighlight">"#ff0000"</item>
```

[Image attached here is because for a comment below]

and when i do, this is how it looks

[image]

Comment: Im sorry i should have posted this in my original question but i already tried this.. it does nothing!

Comment: it should work. actually i have the same type of customization which i've used on a project. and i just tried your exact code into a mock app and it just works well

Comment: i guess you are customizing your action bar. can you post me your action bar or the customized xml code so i can figure out?

Comment: i didn't use the action bar.. i will post the whole xml layout above but its a bit layered with stuff not relevant.

Comment: And did you check the theme overrides in style.xml? because i used your same code and it works perfectly!

Comment: just check my answer i attached a snapshort and the above you see is a EditText which highlighted in blue

Comment: `textColorHighligt` doesn't support opacity does it?

Answer (score 7):

And if you have to change the Marker handle then you should change

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/edittext_handle_selection</item>
<item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/edittext_selection</item>
```

Comment: `android:textColorHighlight` is for highlight color, `colorAccent` is for cursor color.

Answer (score 4):

In code:

```
et.setHighlightColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.highlight));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `android:textColorHighlight` in the EditText element in you layout xml file

Answer (score 1):

In material design you will get the default ascent color in style so the all text selection and other theme would be according to that color. You can change this ascent color in following way -

Go to the style.xml and change the following color -

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item> // Replace this color with your own choice
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a selector to change text colors`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Pressed State -->
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:color="#FF0000" />
<!-- Focused State -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:color="#FF0000" />
<!-- Default State -->
<item android:color="#FFFFFF" />
```

And then set your textColor property to @drawable/selector_name

Comment: nope this doesn't work either.. with your exact code above, my text would be red after a word is complete, but still highlighted with grey  over black just like my screen shot above.

Answer (score 0):

use this code,might be its help you

```
android:textColorHighlight="your color code"
```

Answer (score 0):

well there's a simpler way to do it...I was here to look for an answer, but im answering my own answer.

If you go to the attractions place go all the way down to the letter `T` and there should be an `TextColorHighlight` but if you don't see it the there should be ones
that aren't fully shown so go hover over them and then the full word will show
the showed be little color icons beside them you should press them and select your color. And then go to your code and enter `TextColorHighlight` Press `Tab` and then enter the name of the color, then run it!

Hope that this worked out for you, sorry I couldn't add any pictures of how'd it would of looked. Oh and maybe you're wondering why didn't it automatically do that then have me do it? Now im wondering that too, ill try to see what i can do

Comment: ok nvm i was wrong it deos automatilly deos it for you

Comment: Do you know how to change the color of the underline in edittext, its always green I want to change it blue, how to do it?