# EditText - Text selection background color change programmatically

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext, android-view, android-theme

I am working on dynamic theme apply on Android application concept. I am applying theme color programmatically for all UI. I want to change `EditText` selection background color programmatically. [image]

Any help would be much appreciated. I want to change textselection highlight color.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29795507/8117793 Check this answer

Comment: @TominB I need to change color of text background and not about handle.

Comment: Do you Mean Selection Highlight?

Comment: yes Selection highLight

Comment: @ Samir Batt Check my answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48616746/8117793 Try this.. Hope this may solve your proble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight the selection Use `setHighlightColor` feature in the code for the `EditText`. It is not background color. Its HighLightColor.

**IN CODE**

```
editTextName.setHighlightColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.highlight));
```

Answer (score 2):

Background color as you mentioned in your question is known as **HighlightColor** for `EditText`.

Try this,

```
et.setHighlightColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.highlight));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `EditText` with name `editText` use `setHighlightColor()` method:

```
editText.setHighlightColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether is this you are looking for , but why don't you try:

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorID));
```

Comment: I do not want to set background color. I want to set color which display on text selection. Please read my question carefully

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639594/how-to-change-highlight-color-on-edittext-field) try this out , Sorry for the inconvenience @Samir

Comment: Kindly edit answer. `setHighlightColor`